# <div> tag doesn't affect anything

Tags: html, css

So, I recently had this issue, that I tried to specifically style all "h1" tags with the "div" tag, but it just didn't work. I had to put the "class" values in the "h1" tags manually, which is quite annoying.

Didn't work:

```
<div class="Title">

<h1>Title</h1>

<p>Paragraph</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
h1.Title {color: red}
```

Did work:

```
<h1 class="Title">Title</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

I am pretty new to CSS, so it's very possible I just forgot something or so, and if that's the case, please tell me!

Comment: While the other answers are correct, they're not fixing your CSS issue. The reason h1.title doesn't target the div is that you're telling it to only target h1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just formatting it wrong, nothin too big! CSS inheritance is kinda weird when you start out with it (or seemed weird to me) but it eventually makes a lot of sense. Start with the parent, and then select the child from it. like:

```
parent child {

}
```

So in your case:

```
div h1 { 
    color:red;
}
```

But for your class, you can do this

```
.Title { 
   /* affects all title children */
 }
```

or

```
.Title h1 { 
    /* affects all h1s with a parent of Title */
 }
```

I'm not here to argue about variable initialization, but I would never ever ever use capital letters first in your class or ID declarations. Some people prefer camelCase, but I prefer underlined_naming.

I don't want to berate you for this, but someone here eventually will! Plus, forming good habits now will save you a lot of time fixing them later.

Comment: That explains alot. I'll also remeber to not use capital letters for variable initializations anymore

Answer (score 4):

when you type `h1.title` you're saying "Every h1 element with class='title'" which means that if you put the class title on the div it won't get selected. It's usually better to drop the element selector and just use `.title` in your css so it will hit any element with the class of title.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.title h1 {
   color: red }
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it's difficult to see why. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what you changed, why you changed it, and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just do 
only h1 in title dive will be changed..

```
.Title h1{
color:red;
}
```